# How to close a file from a different JSP page from where it was open

Tags: java, file, jsp

I've a JSP page where a kind of users `users_group_1` need to work with a file. **All of them work with the same file**, so since I'm in JSP, I made a class (`Class1`) with all the methods as **synchronized** to avoid problems using it.

In the JSP for these group of users, I've only one instance for all them, declared like this:

```
<%!
  Class1 my_object = null;
%>
```

Then, when the first user uses the web, it does:

```
if (my_object == null)
{
  my_object = new Class1(file_to_open);
}
```

Then, all the users from the group will be using the same instance.

So now, I need **another JSP page**, that will be open by `user_group_2`, **to close this file and save the work done**.

So I think I need to get the instance of `Class1` used in the JSP and give it to the second one.

How can I do it?

Extra data: `user_group_2` never uses the same JSP page than `user_group_1`, so I can't use request/session/... objects (I think).

Comment: Have a class that is responsible for retrieving the `Class1` instance.  Both JSP1 and JSP2 use that class to get the instance vs creating the instance directly.  Example, `Class1 o = Class1Factory.getInstance()`, where `getInstance()` is a static method.  If your intent is that what is returned is a singleton, then that method can create the `Class1` instance when first invoked, cache it, and return the cached instance in subsequent calls.  Make sure to synchronize things when doing so.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! I should have thought about that. Thanks so much!

Comment: to do so you can also put your object into application  scope and can access anywhere .

Comment: I tried using the factory model, but it becomes useless at the point because it's only shared within the app for the same client (the instance I mean). I will try now the application scope as @Rajeev said!

Comment: I was able to make it through the application scope, thanks @Rajeev ! Please put is as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved  through something like given  below by using `ServletContext` object(application scope).

On  First jsp page where you want to initialize  your object and set it to application scope.

```
<% 
     ProcessFile processFile=(ProcessFile)application.getAttribute("processFile");
     if(null==processFile){
     // make sure that all method of this class is synchronized beacause of multiple users
         processFile=new  ProcessFile("pathToOpenFile");
     }

     application.setAttribute("processFile", processFile); 
     //now processFile available globally. 
    %>
```

And after that on second jsp page you can use that `processFile` object which has been set into application scope like :

```
 <% 
        ProcessFile processFile2=(ProcessFile)application.getAttribute("processFile");
          // now start processing of file 
           if(null!=processFile2){

           processFile2.readFile();
          //open file if not. And read it.  

          //and after that. 
          processFile2.closeFileIfOpen();  
          // do neccesorry checks inside above method while closing file.  
          //all method are synchronized
          }
        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class and have everyone getting an instance of that class.

```
 public class SingletonFile {
      private static SingletonFile instance.
      static {
            instance = new SingletonFile();
      }

      public static SingletonFile getInstance() {
           return instance;
      }

      private SingletonFile () {}

      // public methods for manipulation of files goes here.
 }
```